# SugarCRM REST API set_relationship between Quote and ProductBundles

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM Pro 6.5.5

I need to create a Quote and add Products to it with the REST API. All bundles > Prof the `set_entry`'s work, and the `set_relationship` for ProductBoducts works fine. But, `set_relationship` for Quotes > ProductBundles does not work.

Here is my input for ProductBundles > Products: **this works fine**

```
{
   "session":"5qklti658f0ooou135vt8fkbi4",
   "module":"ProductBundles",
   "module_id":"50b71673-b555-9d68-04c9-508ef9582f47",
   "link_field_name":"products",
   "related_ids":[
      "a9615ab1-cd89-1549-f9b8-508f00c6fa84"
   ]
}
```

Here is my input for Quotes > ProductBundles: **this does not work**

```
{
   "session":"jqodi1pu8u2l8basca1hhcbt27",
   "module":"Quotes",
   "module_id":"bc01a88a-35c9-25ed-dfac-508ef206a264",
   "link_field_name":"product_bundles",
   "related_ids":[
      "50b71673-b555-9d68-04c9-508ef9582f47"
   ]
}
```

**BUT it still returns:**

```
{
   "created":1,
   "failed":0,
   "deleted":0
}
```

But, no record is created in the *`product_bundle_quote`* table.

I have dug into the Sugar code a little, and found something interesting.

In `service/core/SoapHelperWebService.php` on line 735, is this:

```
$mod->$link_field_name->add($related_ids, $name_value_pair);
```

Which calls the `add` method in file `data/Relationships/M2MRelationship.php` on line 118. Interestingly, `$lhsLinkName` is NULL, which causes the method to return false. Here is a snippet:

```
public function add($lhs, $rhs, $additionalFields = array())
{
    $lhsLinkName = $this->lhsLink;
    $rhsLinkName = $this->rhsLink;

    if (empty($lhs->$lhsLinkName) && !$lhs->load_relationship($lhsLinkName))
    {
        $lhsClass = get_class($lhs);
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("could not load LHS $lhsLinkName in $lhsClass");
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($rhs->$rhsLinkName) && !$rhs->load_relationship($rhsLinkName))
    {
        $rhsClass = get_class($rhs);
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("could not load RHS $rhsLinkName in $rhsClass");
        return false;
    }
```

It returns FALSE in the first `if()` block, which means the record is never created.

Also, this shows up in my log: 
`[2139][1][FATAL] could not load LHS  in ProductBundle`

So yeah, I'm stuck here. I tried searching for everything I could, including the error, but I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same thing when using the python library that implements the REST API.  I have an open ticket with support and I'm also looking into it myself as well.  I'll follow up if I learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Sugar bug, which will be fixed in the 6.7 release. In the meantime, check out this forums post for the code fix.

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/create-quote-line-items-web-service-api-83183/

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue for us. Seeing the same above even after applying the patch.

Comment: This bug is unrelated to what the OP is encountering.  I can vouch both for the error, and for the application of this patch not addressing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This does turn out to be a Sugar Bug, but not the one in the other answer.  It's actually related to this bug: [Bug 32064](http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html#issue_32064).  They were able to provide me with a custom module that I could upload and activate to address the issue before release 6.7 when this is slated to be addressed officially.  You'll probably want to contact SugarCRM directly for this workaround, depending on your time frame.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and in order to resolve that i added the below mentioned code in product bundles vardef and it's start working fine.

```
'quotes' =>
    array (

     'name' => 'quotes',
     'type' => 'link',
     'vname'=>'LBL_PRODUCT_BUNDLES',
     'relationship' => 'product_bundle_quote',
     'source'=>'non-db',

),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the quote to products too.
make sure in your quote vardef there's the following:

```
'products' =>
    array (
      'name' => 'products',
      'type' => 'link',
      'relationship' => 'quote_products',
      'vname' => 'LBL_PRODUCTS',
      'source'=>'non-db',
),
```

and in your webservice, set the relationship between quote and products

```
{
    "session":$session_id,
    "module":"Quotes",
    "module_id":$quote_id,
    "link_field_name":"products",
    "related_ids":[
       $product_id 
    ]
}
```

It works for me.